# Need a SQL select statement to return rows that have the same id in one column and distinct value in another column

Tags: sql, oracle, case, window-functions, sql-null

I have a table that contains a group number column and a data column:

| GROUP | DataColumn |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL |
| 1 | NULL |
| 1 | "hello" |
| 1 | NULL |
| 2 | "bye" |
| 2 | "sorry" |
| 3 | NULL |
| 3 | NULL |
| 3 | NULL |

I want to return the string in the `DataColunm` as long as all rows in that group contain a string (no row is null).

If any row in the group is NULL then I'd like to return all rows in that group with NULL in the `DataColumn`.

My desired output would be:

| GROUP | DataColumn |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL |
| 1 | NULL |
| 1 | NULL (swap "hello" to null since the other values for group 1 are null) |
| 1 | NULL |
| 2 | "bye" |
| 2 | "sorry" |
| 3 | NULL |
| 3 | NULL |
| 3 | NULL |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNT()` window function to count all the rows of each `GROUP` and compare the result to the number of the rows with non-null values:

```
SELECT "GROUP",
       CASE 
         WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY "GROUP") = 
              COUNT("DataColumn") OVER (PARTITION BY "GROUP") 
            THEN "DataColumn" 
       END "DataColumn"
FROM tablename;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a6e8df976f48fa0f36eabd4625e3baeb).

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option: check whether number of `null` and `not null` values per each group is a positive number; if so, return `null` for that group.

Sample data:

```
SQL> set null NULL
SQL> with test (cgroup, datacolumn) as
  2    (select 1, null    from dual union all
  3     select 1, null    from dual union all
  4     select 1, 'hello' from dual union all
  5     select 1, null    from dual union all
  6     select 2, 'bye'   from dual union all
  7     select 2, 'sorry' from dual union all
  8     select 3, null    from dual union all
  9     select 3, null    from dual union all
 10     select 3, null    from dual
 11    ),
```

Query begins here:

```
 12  temp as
 13    (select cgroup, datacolumn,
 14       sum(case when datacolumn is null then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by cgroup) cnt_null,
 15       sum(case when datacolumn is null then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by cgroup) cnt_not_null
 16     from test
 17    )
 18  select cgroup,
 19    case when cnt_null > 0 and cnt_not_null > 0 then null
 20         else datacolumn
 21    end as datacolumn
 22  from temp;

    CGROUP DATACOLUMN
---------- ---------------
         1 NULL
         1 NULL
         1 NULL
         1 NULL
         2 bye
         2 sorry
         3 NULL
         3 NULL
         3 NULL

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```